# Totem & VLC not working

Tags: video, vlc, totem

Totem (or "Videos") & VLC media player is not working, they both refuse to play any videos of any format i tried. By "Refuse" i mean crashing, not responding, or even just plain old skipping the entire video. Ive tried everything, from downloading H.264 decoder, reinstalling VLC, to installing Ubuntu-Restricted-Areas, changing tiny pieces of the codes, etc. Please help!

Comment: P.S. some people say that it's because the video is in a windows file, and so it can't play it unless ubuntu already has Ubuntu-restricted-areas installed, and should only work if it is on the ubuntu files. Well, it IS on the ubuntu files so to say.

Comment: run vlc from the command line and post the output here, provide us with some details...

Comment: VLC_VERBOSE
              The   level  of  verbosity  for  log  messages  (0:  silent,  1:
              error/info, 2: warning, 3: debug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact it was just that the name of the file i was trying to play was wrong. had to be mp4. sorry for all the fuss and everything.

Comment: lol..........:)

Answer (score 0):

by ubuntu-restricted-areas you mean

```
ubuntu-restricted-extras.
```

Its a meta package which will install nearly every media codec

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant. lol